# Skip First or Last Slide in NivoSlider - jQuery Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

Does anyone know how I can skip the **first** or **last** slide in my *[NivoSlider 3.1](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)* installation?

**Background:** I add my images to the slideshow dynamically using *WordPress* custom fields and due to a `strange quirk`, it won't display the slideshow unless I have at least 1 image already in there.

**Is it possible to tell NivoSlider to ignore the FIRST or LAST slide?**

So, my markup could be:

```
<div id="slider" class="slider nivoSlider">
<img src="1.jpg" /> <!-- Ignore this ALWAYS -->
<img src="wp-img-1.jpg" />
<img src="another-wp-img-2.jpg" />
<img src="yet-another-wp-img-3.jpg" />
</div>
```

So, for instance [here](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/), it would skip `Wall-E` or `Finding Nemo` altogether, not even displaying it.

Many thanks for any help with this - totally racking my brains for a few days now :-)

Comment: You could use jquerey to on dom ready, move out the images you don't want then start up the gallery?

Comment: Aaaah, good point. I am very new to jQuery and using the DOM. Is there any chance you could show me how this could be achieved?

Comment: many thanks, take your time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should help you out a bit.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //set up vars
    var slider = $('#slider');
    var firstImage = $('#slider img:first');
    var lastImage = $('#slider img:last');

    //Take them out of the gallery
    firstImage.remove();
    lastImage.remove();

    //run photo gallery stuff

    //Now add images back in
    slider.prepend(firstImage);
    slider.append(lastImage);
});
```

**EDIT**

```
    $(window).load(function() {

//set up vars
var slider = $('#slider');
var firstImage = $('#slider img:first');
var lastImage = $('#slider img:last');

//Take them out of the gallery
firstImage.remove();
lastImage.remove();

    $('.slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'slideInLeft', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices: 15, // For slice animations
        boxCols: 8, // For box animations
        boxRows: 4, // For box animations
        animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
        pauseTime: 3000, // How long each slide will show
        startSlide: 1, // Set starting Slide (0 index)    
        controlNav: false, // 1,2,3... navigation
        controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance: true, // Force manual transitions
        prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
        nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
        randomStart: false, // Start on a random slide   
        directionNav:true,
        directionNavHide:false,
        afterLoad: function(){
            //Now add images back in
            slider.prepend(firstImage);
            slider.append(lastImage);
        } // Triggers when slider has loaded
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect. I'll give this a try right now. Thanks again for taking the time to look at this issue :)

Comment: no worries, so long as you call the photogallery manually you'll have no problems. ideally, you'd want a callback from the gallery's code so that you add them back in once the gallery has been added

Comment: Cool. I'm fairly confused already sadly :-/ Is this to go in my `<head>` or inside `jquery.nivo.slider.js` somewhere? Sorry for the noobyness here. --- if it's easier, I could post a link to a jsfiddle using nivoslider?

Comment: no worries, do you have the code that you use to called nivo? if you do maybe add that to a jsfiddle for me to look at.

Comment: Sorry, took a bit more than 2 minutes :: http://jsfiddle.net/jK3by/ Thanks `so much` for any help here.

Comment: So sorry for the delay. I will try this shortly. Does the edited code just go in my head tag or in the jQuery.novo.slider.ja file? Sorry again for the time delay in my reply.

Comment: With a bit of jiggery pokery I think I've managed to get it working. Here's my WP code: http://pastebin.com/ABsHL5hd & my jQuery code (now inside `<head>` : http://pastebin.com/vdFXCP4g. Thank you so much for your help & patience throughout this. Have a great weekend and Christmas / New Year when it comes :-)